# How to give a name for recording video file instead of default "video.mp4" in Selenium Dynamic Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, serenity-bdd

Selenium Dynamic Grid normally populates the video with "video.mp4" name, but I want to customize the file name for each test scenario. That is to say I want to give a different name for each video file. By the way, dynamic grid creates an output directory with a session id and similarly I want to customize its name too.

Currently =>

```
-> assets/0ee7055665ae578cac71ed0a6d97c91a
       -> sessionCapabilities.json
       -> video.mp4
```

Instead I want to the following =>

```
-> assets/succesfullLoginScenario
       -> sessionCapabilities.json
       -> succesfullLoginScenario.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename each downloaded file to any custom name.
This is the simplest and the best approach for this problem.

Comment: I am developing automated e2e tests. I am using selenium java and cucumber with serenity. I need to give the names of the gherkin scenarios to the files automatically.  If I can pass the video file names as driver a capability in the code, I will be able to reach the target I want. otherwise I will have to write a script that will update the names.